# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm building a server side application in Kotlin, using the Ktor framework. When I run the application, I receive a `NoClassDefFoundError`. The stacktrace is shown below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.<init>(JWTVerifier.java:28)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier$BaseVerification.build(JWTVerifier.java:316)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier$BaseVerification.build(JWTVerifier.java:304)
    at com.example.auth.JwtService.<init>(JwtService.kt:18)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:44)
```

It seems to point to something to do with my verifier variable shown below in my JWTVerifier class.

```
val verifier: JWTVerifier = JWT
        .require(algorithm)
        .withIssuer(issuer)
        .build()
```

Help would be most appreciated.

Comment: is it a gradle project? Do you have jackson library in the dependency? which version?

Comment: Could you please share a complete code snippet or a sample project to reproduce the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception? There is probably some problem with the `jackson-databind`  dependency because `java-jwt` artifact requires it https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.18.1/jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.

My project was running without issues (before Sept 15) and i haven't updated any dependencies. Then it started crashing with `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer`

What fixed it was updating Ktor. I was using version `1.5.4` and updated to `1.6.3`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding jackson dependency to build.gradle file

```
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-jackson:$ktor_version"
```